# What is the meaning of .html(data) code in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a script where it pass data into parameter, i have this references and it works in my application , but i still confuse about this line of code . here is the code

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#dataselect").change(function () {
        var urls = "{% url 'polls:load-column' %}";  
        var column = $(this).val(); 

        $.ajax({                     
          url: urls,                    
          data: {
            'column': column   
          },
          success: function(data) {   
              $(".columnselect").html(data);   # this is what im confused of 
          },
          error: function(data)
          {
            alert("error occured");
          }
        });
      });
      });
  </script>
```

i really confuse at $(".columnselect").html(data); -> why .html(data)? why we must passed the data  value(which we send to the views(backend)) to the html function that i write in views

if you want to see the views

```
def list_all_column(request):
    import cx_Oracle
    data_name = request.GET.get('column',1)
    dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('', '', sid='') 
    conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user=r'', password='', dsn=dsn_tns) 
    c = conn.cursor() 
    c.execute("select column_name from all_tab_cols where table_name = '"+data_name+"'")
    c.rowfactory = makeDictFactory(c)

    columnalldata = []
    for rowDict in c:
        columnalldata.append(rowDict['COLUMN_NAME'])
    context = {
        'obj3' : columnalldata
    }
    return render(request,'column-list.html',context)
```

i hope someone can explain this line of code to me , thankyou

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/html/#html2

Comment: $(".columnselect").html(data);
data :- it response from API, 
".columnselect" :- this is class of element, 
.html :- html is jquery function which add/replace html data inside ".columnselect" class element

Comment: $(".columnselect").html(data);  what this function do is like you are making request to the server and in success you will get response from the server which gives you data you asked for and then .columnselect is class name of the div so this function $(".columnselect").html(data); will replace the data of div having class .columnselect with data in html(data) and if you use $(".columnselect").append(data); then this function will append data to the div

Comment: oh i see now , okay i get it now , thankyou for the explanation @PraveenPatel

Comment: and thankyou for the full explanation @coder_B

Answer (score 0):

This [`.html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/)*(it will replace all the existing markup)* is a jQuery method to put any markup. These markup can be either dynamically generated or might be get it in the response of a ajax call.

It is as similar to `.innerHTML` of javascript.

other than this you can use:

- .append()
- .prepend()
- .appendTo()
- .prependTo()
- .after()
- .before()

etc.

Comment: hmm so why pass "data" parameter to html , what did the column-list.html(in the views) will get from the data parameter

Comment: `.html(data)` here data holds some markup string which is getting inserted. You can see you have an ajax call. when call has a success `success: function(data) {` you get the response in the `data` param, so this should have to be put in the specific column.